# Do need to calculate PCA every time I add new item to dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I want to visualise dataset of high dimensional data. And there comes PCA with dimensionality reduction. When I upload a new image and want to see where it is placed compared to images that are already in my dataset.

Do I need to calculate PCA every time I add new image?

My intuition says yes, because when I add high volume of new images I'm going to drastically change properties of dataset thus change PC1 and PC2 directions.

I'm using python with scikit-learn PCA and I'm talking about fit_transform method. Or should I change approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: +1 I have had this question as well. I think I would probably run PCA `fit_transform()` again after adding new datapoints to the training set, but I am not sure what would be wrong with just using `transform()` method of a previously fitted pca.

Comment: @SRMaiti The question tries to state what might be wrong: eventually, so much information would be lost that the old PCA would be of questionable value.  However, that is unclear because we haven't been told what the objective of this procedure is, nor what the important constraints are.  For instance, why can't the dataset be visualized once and for all by conducting a PCA on all the images?